# Invertibility of a square matrix with zero diagonal elements and positive non-diagonal elements

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, singularity-theory

$M$ is square and
$$M(i,j)=0, i=j$$
$$M(i,j)>0, i\ne j$$
Is $M$ full-rank or invertible?

Actually the $M$ I am studying has much stronger properties but I guess the simple conditions above might be enough to make $M$ non-singular. The stronger properties of $M$ are:

1. All elements in $M$ are non-negative integers between $0$ and $N$;
2. The sum of each row is equal to $N$.

---

#### Edit

$N$ is not the dimension of $M$. It's just a constant positive integer.

I did search for this problem, but it seemed there was no much work on such matrices. It looks easy, but I don't know how to prove it and I couldn't find a counter-example either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The matrix $M$ doesn't have to invertible. I give a simple counterexample here.
$$M=\begin{pmatrix}
0&2&1&1\\
2&0&1&1\\
1&1&0&2\\
1&1&2&0
\end{pmatrix}$$
You will see $r_1+r_2-r_3-r_4=0$ which indicates they are linear dependent.

Comment: Thanks a lot Shuchang. What if I have even stronger condition on $M$ -- the subdiagonal entries, which are directly below and to the left of the main diagonal, are also all zeros. Other properties of $M$ remain the same. Must $M$ be nonsingular now? ($Dim(M) \ge 3$)

Comment: @TomSmith Triangular matrix is invertible if and only if it doesn't have zero diagonal element.

Comment: Thanks. I meant only the entries on the diagnoal and subdiagonal of $M$ were zeros so it was not a triangular matrix. An example could be changing your matrix above to: $$M= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\ 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix}$$ Do you think $M$ with such constraints must be nonsingular?

Comment: Sorry for any confusion and thanks for your help.

Comment: @TomSmith Oh, sorry. But still, invertiability still cannot be guaranteed. A counterexample is given using 6 by 6 matrix by considering the first 3 rows add up to the last 3 rows.